# is there an easy way to find out when an issue was closed

Tags: github, gitlab, github-api

I'm researching for my company if we should migrate over to gitlab (From github).. github's issue api seems very [rich](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues) and it has stuff like `closed_at` for an issue (it's very important for me to grab/analyze historical data about when issues got created/closed).

In gitlab's api doc for [issues](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html).. i don't see a similar field.. all i see is a `state` field (ie state: opened/closed/merged etc).. and i see a `created_at` and `updated_at`.. but i don't see any `closed_at`

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`lib/api/issues.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/d73e1288595ef673b2d9c3024d7fe3909dac7184/lib/api/issues.rb), the information `closed_at` is part of the issue.

Its [`Entity::Issue`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/999ae7f76b275d4b8527a7ebbc012b20220e22b5/lib/api/entities.rb#L169-L173) and [`Entity::ProjectEntity`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/999ae7f76b275d4b8527a7ebbc012b20220e22b5/lib/api/entities.rb#L153-L158)however does not expose that field.

```
expose :state, :created_at, :updated_at
```

That could be as simple at implementing a merge request for the project, to add that field to `Entity::Issue`.

Comment: ok so technically I can fork gitlab's code, modify it as i wish and host my own gitlab version on my own servers right? that would be an immediate fix to this problem (although i'll have to deal with maintenance and all that jazz)

my other option is to send a PR for the guys and hope that some day they'll accept it (ie if i wanted this feature to be available on the _hosted_ version of gitlab) is that right?

Comment: @abbood Yes, that would at least allow you to validate this patch locally, before sending a PR.